# Proguard with Android and Google API Client

Tags: android, proguard, google-api-java-client

first of all, sorry if this topic has been answered, but I have not found it...

I'm new with Android and Proguard. At the ending of developing my appication, I want to reduce its size using proguard, of course. As I am using some libraries from google api client in my application, I've added them as external jars.

Well, my app is working ok without passing proguard step, but when I try to export it, it begins my headache. A lot of warnings that I don't know how skip or arrange. Something as this:

```
[2012-03-05 07:20:06 - CollaJoveThreads] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2012-03-05 07:20:06 - CollaJoveThreads] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2012-03-05 07:20:06 - CollaJoveThreads] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2012-03-05 07:20:06 - CollaJoveThreads] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2012-03-05 07:20:06 - CollaJoveThreads] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2012-03-05 07:20:06 - CollaJoveThreads] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
```

and more similar.

I have followed the Google developers recomendations, and added this lines to my proguard.cfg:

```
# Needed by google-api-client to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault,*Annotation*

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
```

but it continues appearing all these warning messages. And when I tried to use '-dontwarn' option, my app crashes.

I have read these questions, and more:

- [Proguard and Android :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540905/proguard-and-android)
- [Android & Proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188059/android-proguard)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, I found it: it was missing 'jsr305-1.3.9' jar file (I didn't realize before). Thanks for all.

Answer (score 16):

Hi I know that this was already solved by adding in the `jsr305` jar file to your project. However it took me a while to work out where I could find this jar and what to do with it.

You can get the latest version of this jar at [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305) Download the latest jar and put it in your `libs` folder, then add it to your **build path** in Eclipse and everything should be right to go.

This fixed all of my problems as well.

Comment: For Gradle users, just add `compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2'` in build.gradle dependencies.